# Allow users to set permissions for profile fields

Tags: users

I would like users to be able to determine whether a field is displayed publicly. For example, their real name is required for the site, but I don't want to force users to display it.

Comment: What version of Drupal? Are you using the core profile module or a contrib module such as content profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without information on what version of Drupal you are using or what you are using for profiles, here is a suggestion for each type of profile on Drupal 6:

Using the core profile module, check out [Profile Privacy](http://drupal.org/project/profile_privacy)

Using [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile), take a look at [CCK Privacy](http://drupal.org/project/privacy)